# php sqlsrv insert failed

Tags: php, html, sql-server, microsoft-dynamics

I'm attempting to insert a row into Microsoft dynamics RMS database through a web interface.  I can run the insert from the Store Operations Manager (command line?) and it works great, but when i try to run it from my PHP script using sqlsrv it dumps an 515 error saying that it cannot insert a null value into an ID column.

I feel like the error is something with the sqlsrv talking to the database rather than the database itself because i can run the same line directly and it creates the new row.

I tried this with params the first few times but took it out in the interest of trouble shooting.  i got the same error with both methods.

error message:

> ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 23000 [SQLSTATE] => 23000 [1] => 515 [code] => 515 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'OMGHQ.dbo.Customer'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'OMGHQ.dbo.Customer'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 3621 [code] => 3621 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. ) )

```
    $conn = sqlConnection();

if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$itlquery = "DECLARE @itemID INT
            DECLARE @newQuantity INT
            SET @itemID = $itemID
            SET @newQuantity = $newQuantity
            INSERT INTO inventorytransferlog (itemID, quantity, cashierID, type, cost) VALUES (@itemID, @newQuantity - (SELECT TOP 1 quantity FROM item WHERE id = @itemID), 6, 5, (SELECT TOP 1 cost FROM item WHERE id = @itemID));";

echo $itlquery;

$itlstatement = sqlsrv_query($conn,$itlquery);

if($itlstatement === false)
{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without knowing what your php variables are ($itemID and $newQuantity) it is much safer to use parameters as follows.  This is a prepared statement, and has the added benefit protecting against some SQL injection.

```
$itlquery = "INSERT INTO inventorytransferlog (itemID, quantity, cashierID, type, cost) VALUES (?, ? - (SELECT TOP 1 quantity FROM item WHERE id = ?), 6, 5, (SELECT TOP 1 cost FROM item WHERE id = ?));";

echo $itlquery;

$itlstatement = sqlsrv_query($conn,$itlquery,array($itemId,$newQuantity,$itemId,$itemId));
```

**EDIT:**
While the above is correct, it's not the answer to your question. You must have an `ID` column on your `Customer` table which is not nullable.  perhaps it is the primary key and is not auto-increment. So you must either specify it in your insert, or change the schema to make it nullable or auto-increment (if it is not primary key)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  I checked the schema for the table and the ID column is set to is_identity = true.  also when i have php echo back the SQL statement and run it directly it works as it should, so i'm left very confused about why it's failing from inside php.

Comment: hm ok, could your php environment be connecting to a different sql server perhaps?

Comment: <facepalm>DO'H!  fml  thanks a million for pointing me in the correct direction.  </facepalm>